# переключение меню по нескольким сценариям vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Меню переключается по нажатию на кнопки NOT и ATCHETECTURE, а также по нажатию на тумблер, но почему-то тумблер не работает как нужно(при нажатии на него switchOn не меняется с true на false и соответственно меню не переключается). В чем может быть ошибка?

```
     <template>
    <div class="nav-menu">
           <div
           v-for="(title, index) in ['not', 'archetecture']"
            :class="['accordion__title', {'active': index == activeIndex}]"
           :key="`${title}_${title}`"
           @click="getCategoriesTitle(title, index)">{{title}}
            <div v-if="index % 2 === 0" class="switch-btn-wrapper"
            @click="getCategoriesTitle(switchOn ? 'archetecture' : 'not')"
               >
                <div class="switch-btn" :class="{'switch-on': switchOn}"
                >
        </div> 
    </div>    
 </div>
                   
        <div class="accordion" 
        v-for="(item, index) in NAV_TITLES"
        :key="`${item}_${index}`">
            <ul>
              <div class="accordion__submenu submenu">
            <li 
                :class="['submenu submenu__item', {'active': index === activeItem}]"
                @click="getCategoriesItem(item, index)"
                >{{item}}         
                </li>          
              </div>
            </ul>
           
        </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
export default {
    name: 'NavMenu',
    data: () => ({
        activeIndex: 1,
        activeItem: null,
        isActive: false,
        switchOn: true,
    }),
    computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['NAV_LINKS', 'NAV_TITLES']),
    },
    methods: {
          ...mapMutations(['CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU', 'CHANGE_CURRENT_TITLE']),

        getCategoriesTitle(title, index) {
            this.CHANGE_CURRENT_TITLE(title)
               this.switchOn = !this.switchOn
            this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === index ? this.activeIndex : index
        },
        getCategoriesItem(navItem, index) {
            this.CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU(navItem)
            this.activeItem = this.activeItem === index ? this.activeItem : index
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Vuex:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({

state: {
    currentTitle: 'archetecture',
    currentNav: 'interior',
},
getters:  {
    NAV_TITLES: (state) => {
        let titles = {
            not: ['commercial', 'video', '3D art'],
            archetecture: ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation'],
        }
        if (state.currentTitle === 'not') 
        return titles.not

        if (state.currentTitle === 'archetecture')
        return titles.archetecture
    },
    NAV_LINKS: (state) => {
        let links = {
            interior: [
                {   
                    id: 1,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/1.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/9.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {   
                    id: 1111,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/1.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 13,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/13.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {   
                    id: 14,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/14.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 15,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/15.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
            ],
            exterior: [
                {
                    id: 1993,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/13.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {   
                    id: 1664,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/14.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 1995,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/15.jpg"),
                    name: 'interior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 333,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/3.jpg"),
                    name: 'exterior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 44,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/4.jpg"),
                    name: 'exterior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 55,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/5.jpg"),
                    name: 'exterior',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
               
            ],
            vr: [
                {
                    id: 66,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/6.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 77,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/7.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 78,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/8.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 2007,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/26.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 2996,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/25.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 9925,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/24.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 2443,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/23.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 5622,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/22.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 2122,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/21.jpg"),
                    name: 'vr',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
               
            ],
            animation: [
                {
                    id: 99,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/9.jpg"),
                    name: 'animation',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 100,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/10.jpg"),
                    name: 'animation',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 1231,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/11.jpg"),
                    name: 'animation',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
            ],
            commercial: [
                {
                    id: 27,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/26.jpg"),
                    name: 'commercial',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 26,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/25.jpg"),
                    name: 'commercial',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 25,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/24.jpg"),
                    name: 'commercial',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 23,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/23.jpg"),
                    name: 'commercial',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {}},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 22,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/22.jpg"),
                    name: 'commercial',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
                {
                    id: 21,
                    src: require("../assets/img/gallery/21.jpg"),
                    name: 'commercial',
                    route: {name: 'Gallery', params: {
                    }},
                    active: ['Company']
                },
               
            ],
        }


        if (state.currentNav === 'interior') 
        return links.interior

        if (state.currentNav === 'exterior')
         return links.exterior

         if (state.currentNav === 'vr')
         return links.vr

         if (state.currentNav === 'animation')
         return links.animation

         if (state.currentNav === 'commercial')
         return links.commercial
    }
},

mutations: {
    CHANGE_CURRENT_MENU(state, value) {
       state.currentNav = value
       
    },
    CHANGE_CURRENT_TITLE(state, value) {
        state.currentTitle = value
    }
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

исходя из вашего кода состояние меняется. обратите внимание на консоль.
скорее всего не обновляется ДОМ.
к сожалению, вы вставили в пример Vuex данные, к которым у меня нет доступа, чтобы более углубленно рассмотреть ваш пример и помочь.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        activeIndex: 1,
        activeItem: null,
        isActive: false,
        switchOn: true
    }),
    methods: {
        getCategoriesTitle(title, index) {
               this.switchOn = !this.switchOn
            this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === index ? this.activeIndex : index
            console.log(this.switchOn);
            console.log(this.activeIndex);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
           <div
           v-for="(title, index) in ['not', 'archetecture']"
            :class="['accordion__title', {'active': index == activeIndex}]"
           :key="`${title}_${title}`"
           @click="getCategoriesTitle(title, index)">{{title}}
            <div v-if="index % 2 === 0" class="switch-btn-wrapper"
            @click="getCategoriesTitle(switchOn ? 'archetecture' : 'not')"
               >
                <div class="switch-btn" :class="{'switch-on': switchOn}"
                >
        </div> 
    </div>    
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Данные из Vuex добавила в код. А почему DOM обновляется при нажатии на archetecture/not, но при этом игнорирует клик по тумблеру?